# latex classicthesis :: change the start location of the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, classicthesis

I'm using classicthesis for my dissertation. By default the TOC begins with "List of Figures", "List of Tables", and "Listings" as can be seen in the Contents.tex source file.

I would like the TOC to list "Dedication", "Acknowledgements", "Foreword", and "Abstract" before "List of Figures", etc.

I have attempted to do this by adding the following code just before the code for "List of Figures" in Contents.tex.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Dedication}{Dedication}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Acknowledgements}{Acknowledgements}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Preface}{Foreword}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Abstract}{Abstract}
```

This places these four entries into the TOC in the correct position, but they all get assigned the same page number: the roman page number that immediately follows the TOC (the same page number as "List of Figures").

How do I get the TOC to recognize the correct roman page numbers of these four preceding chapters?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need `\clearpage\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline` (and no `\pdfbookmark`).

Comment: Thank you, egreg. I just tried this and it made no change to my TOC. Do you suppose that I need some labeling code in each of my four chapter files, e.g., Dedication.tex?

Comment: Compile another time: changes to the `.toc` file are obeyed after two runs of LaTeX.

Comment: I tried this too; no change.  To clarify, these are my four code lines now:

    \clearpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
    \clearpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
    \clearpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
    \clearpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

Comment: The `\clearpage...` commands should go before the dedication, acknowledgment and so on.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, probably due to ambiguity. Would you be willing to type out the code exactly as it should appear in the Contents.tex file? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not being clear. The Dedication, Acknowledgements, Foreword, and Abstract appear in the document before the TOC. The "List of Figures", "List of Tables", and "Listings" appear in the document after the TOC. But I want the TOC to show all of these chapters/sections, i.e., to refer to chapters/sections above it and below it. Sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: My apology, egreg. <<slapping self upside head>> Once I put the \clearpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{...} line at the beginning of each of the appropriate files (instead of putting them in the Contents.tex file), the TOC did the right thing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do, for instance,

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}

Text of the acknowledgments.
```

A simpler way, when using as base class `scrbook` or `scrreprt`, is to say

```
\addchap{Acknowledgments}
```

that does automatically the addition to the table of contents (`hyperref` takes care of the bookmarks).